# Registering for Display Reconfiguration Callbacks

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, callback

I'm putting together a Mac OS X Application and I'm trying to register to receive Display Reconfiguration notices, but I'm very lost right now. I've been reading Apple's documentation and some forums posts, etc., but everything seems to assume a better knowledge of things than I apparently possess. I understand that I have to request the callback inside a run loop for it to work properly. I don't know how to set up a basic run loop for it, though. I also feel like the example Apple has in their documentation is missing stuff they are expecting me to already know. To display my ignorance here is what I feel like things should look like.

```
NSRunLoop *rLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
codeToStartRunLoop

 void MyDisplayReconfigurationCallBack (
                                       CGDirectDisplayID display,
                                       CGDisplayChangeSummaryFlags flags,
                                       void *userInfo);
{
    if (flags & kCGDisplayAddFlag) {
        NSLog (@"Display Added");
    }
    else if (kCGDisplayRemoveFlag) {
        NSLog (@"Display Removed");
    }
 }

CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback(MyDisplayReconfigurationCallBack, NULL);
```

The actual code I got was from Apple's Example, but it tells me that `flags` is an undeclared identifier at this point and won't compile. Not that it would work right since I don't have it in a run loop. I was hoping to find a tutorial somewhere that explains registering for system callback in a run loop but have not been successful. If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd super appreciate it.

(I'm sure that you'll be able to tell from my question that I'm very green. I taught myself Objective-C out of a book as my first programming language. I skipped C, so every once in a while I hit a snag somewhere that I can't figure out.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're writing a Mac OS X application, the AppKit has already [set up a run loop](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/AddingBehaviortoaCocoaProgram/AddingBehaviorCocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH5-SW26) for you, so you don't need to worry about that part. You really only need to create your own run loop in Cocoa when you are also creating your own thread.

For the "undeclared identifier" part, it looks like it's due to a typo/syntax mistake:

```
void MyDisplayReconfigurationCallBack (CGDirectDisplayID display, 
                                       CGDisplayChangeSummaryFlags flags,
                                       void *userInfo);
// Semicolon makes this an invalid function definition^^
{
    // This is an anonymous block,* and flags wasn't declared in it
    if (flags & kCGDisplayAddFlag) {
    // etc.
}
```

Also, unlike some other languages, you can't declare or define functions inside of other functions, methods, or blocks* -- they have to be at the top level of the file. You can't put this in the same place where you call `CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback`.

Just as an sample (I have no idea what the rest of your code really looks like):

```
// MyClassThatIsInterestedInDisplayConfiguration.m
#import "MyClassThatIsInterestedInDisplayConfiguration.h"

// Define callback function at top level of file
void MyDisplayReconfigurationCallBack (
                                   CGDirectDisplayID display,
                                   CGDisplayChangeSummaryFlags flags,
                                   void *userInfo)
{
    if (flags & kCGDisplayAddFlag) {
        NSLog (@"Display Added");
    }
    else if (kCGDisplayRemoveFlag) {
        NSLog (@"Display Removed");
    }
}

@implementation MyClassThatIsInterestedInDisplayConfiguration

- (void) comeOnBabyAndDoTheRegistrationWithMe {
    // Register callback function inside a method
    CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback(MyDisplayReconfigurationCallBack, 
                                     NULL);
}

@end
```

---

*The basic C curly-brace-delimited thing, not the new cool [Obj-C ad hoc function thing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/).

Comment: The declaring the function at the top level of the file (and the syntax error ;) is exactly what I was missing. The samples Apple provides in their documentation doesn't really make that clear. Probably because you're supposed to already know that and it's redundant. Thanks Josh!

Comment: Yes, the sample code has to assume a lot of knowledge so that it can be concise; otherwise any given piece would be ten pages long. Glad I could help!

Comment: (As an aside: don't worry so much about "being a beginner" -- you ask well-thought-out and -written questions, and I think people here are happy to help even if they're "basic".)